# Can we change the visibility setting of a custom setting in managed package

Tags: managed-package

I have a managed package which uses a custom setting.
But this is not visible once the package was loaded into the org. Based on some google search i came to know that this would not be available if the visibilty setting is protected.

This package is **released package** and not Beta, its just been tested out in a demo org and not installed in any other external org. When i try to change the setting in the dev env. the option for changing visibility is disabled.

How can i change the visibility of the setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. Once a component is packaged it is unable to be changed.

All the information about Packaging can be found [here](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf)

It is possible for Salesforce to roll back a managed package from final to beta, but there are strict conditions, the package can not be installed in any orgs. So it sounds like you are in luck, uninstall it from the demo org and log a case with Salesforce.

Comment: No way!! Did not know we could request Salesforce do a rollback like that.  To do any real testing of a managed package I need a non-dev org which requires a final release, knowing that if there is an issue it could get rolled back before a customer installs is huge!!

Comment: @Ralph I would check with Salesforce about this, I'm not certain about the criteria i.e does having older versions of your managed package installed exclude you. The only time we did this was the same situation as Prady. First ever final package limited test installs.

Comment: @Ralph another solution to your non dev org testing problem would be to spin up an org through the partner portal, these orgs allow beta managed packages to be installed

Comment: great suggestion, still learning everything that is available to me in the partner portal

Comment: Thanks @DanielBlackhall. I have logged a case with salesforce. Will keep you guys updated